# Java: Android dev: "The method getHolder() is undefined for the type GameView"

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to follow the tutorial here:

http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame2.html

But have hit a snag. For some reason, eclipse doesn't recognise getHolder() and gives me the following error:

The method getHolder() is undefined for the type GameView

And the following solutions:

Change to getHandler(...);
Create method getHolder()

The code is pretty much the same as the tutorial, but here is what I have anyway:

```
package com.example.killthemall;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;

public class GameView extends View {

private Bitmap bmp;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(new Callback() {

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
               Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
               onDraw(c);
               holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                      int width, int height) {

        }

 }); 


    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 10, 10, null);
}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getHolder()` is a method of `SurfaceView`, and you're extending `View`. Change to:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView {
```

Comment: Ah, what a simple and embarrassing error. This fixed it all up. Thanks!